# Symfony sonata EntityType edit form - select - get other that current

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I have simple form generator field like this:

```
$formMapper->add('project',EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Project::class,
        ]);
```

It is field for select parent in tree data structure.
It works very well in ADD, but in Edit i dont want to project with id X show as possible to select parent for project with id X

[image]

I am trying to use 'query_builder' property, but dont know how to catch id of current editing item from Admin class.

How to catch this id or simplest exclusion id of current editing item in select?

Comment: Does the given answer help you? If not, please let us know. If so, please accept (and maybe upvote) the answer. Ignoring an answer completely is a bit unkind.

Comment: @Stephan Vierkant Thx for some tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose your FormType is mapped on your edited item. Therefore, you could go with something like (class / fields / entity names to be replaced by yours) :

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
class ProjectFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $currentId = $builder->getData()->getId();
        $builder->add('project', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => Project::class,     
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($currentId) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('p')
                           ->where('p.id != :idCurrent')
                           ->setParameter('idCurrent', $currentId);
             },  
       ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Project::class,
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx. Your answer is good but after some time I found easiest solution to this situation. AbstractAdmin have getSubject() method.

Comment: Good to know, I must admit I'm not very familiar with sonata admin, I gave you a more general answer which works outside of sonata context.